# Where can I find a remote mains socket for my electrical heater?

Tags: heating, home-automation

I have been looking around for a remote mains socket which will operate my heater in my office at the end of the 70 feet garden. I want to be able to switch on the heater from the house.

The label on the heater says `250 Volt - 50Hz - 2500 Watt` so the plug must support this voltage (amp?). 
I checked this [np8800](http://www.audon.co.uk/np8800.html) but this only supports up to 6 amp and the seller said it won't support my heater.

I live in UK by the way.

Comment: Amps = Watts/Volts. Therefore A = 2500W/250V = 10A. Most outlets should support this fine. You linked to a USB-controlled outlet. Do you intend on controlling the switch with a computer?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be via computer. If there is any remote controlled switch that will operate 70 feet on open, I'd definitely prefer that.

Comment: This sounds to me like you need to run a new circuit (in some conduit) from your house to your office. Wire a switch inside your house and possibly a second switch in the office to control the outlet with the heater.

Comment: Well, I really don't want to do that :) It's too much hassle. I am looking for something easier, like a remote control. But thanks for your suggestions.